# Which residuals - from gls or summary(gls) should I use?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, residuals, generalized-least-squares

In R, gls object contains "residuals" and the summary(gls) object contains residuals. Both differ from each other. Which is the one I should use for checking the normality?

```
> shapiro.test(summary(m)$residuals)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  summary(m)$residuals
W = 0.92493, p-value = 0.5622

> shapiro.test(m$residuals)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  m$residuals
W = 0.92671, p-value = 0.000242
```

Let's make it model agnostic.

EDIT: just answered. The residuals from the model are just 5 quantiles of the raw residuals.

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit.. seems like you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably used to the `summary(object)` function from the base, in which case the residuals of the object are equivalent to the residuals of the summary of the object (indeed, `summary` just stores the residuals in the class `summary.lm`). But with gls, you're probably using `summary.gls()` which, as mentioned in the documentation ([see here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-143/topics/summary.gls)), defines the residual component as:

> residuals 
> if more than five observations are used in the gls fit, a
> vector with the minimum, first quartile, median, third quartile, and
> maximum of the residuals distribution; else the residuals.